# Concat a VarChar and Date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create another column where I concatenate `ID` and `Date_`. `ID` is `Varchar(32)` and `Date_` is `Datetime`. When I `concat` the two and create a new column called `UniqueValue` I get the error message:

> data type are incompatible.

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT        
    ID, PROP, DATE_, VALUE_, Model, ETLUPDATED, 
    CONCAT(ID, Date_) As UniqueValue
FROM            
    dbo.Retail2
WHERE        
    (PROP = 'vol') 
    AND (DATEDIFF(YEAR, DATE_, GETDATE()) <= 2) 
    AND (Model = 'base')
```

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: vincenthavinh beat me to it: [CONVERT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) is the function you're looking for :) Please be sure to "upvote" and "accept" his response :)

Comment: No - concat works just fine with different datatypes - including datetime. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e79fbbbb613408614527506217f389f1). Something else is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want your new column type to be `VARCHAR`.

You should try to convert the Datetime argument: [Sql-server Convert() tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

Edit this part:

```
concat(ID, convert(VARCHAR(20), Date_, 120) )
```

You could also add another specific date format with the optional parameter. Replace 120 by whatever you need or remove it for default string format. (see doc linked)

*Edit: it seems `convert()` is exclusive to SQL Server. Since you tagged SQL Server in your post it should work though.*

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @marc_s Good point. It s up to him to define a good length taking in account his id length + datetime string length. `convert(VARCHAR(60), ....)` for example

Comment: Oops mea culpa, the length of varchar is only the one of the datetime string. I'll lower to 20 in my example to fit the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` string format which is imo the cleanest.